# How to construct an sqlite table that assign and returns IDs to any name?

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, indexing, primary-key

I would like to have an sqlite table that maps names into unique IDs. I can create this table in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE name_to_id (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)
```

With a select statement I can get the row containing a needed name and get from this row the corresponding ID.

The problem appears if I try to get ID for a name that is not yet in the table. The expected behavior in this case is that the new name will be added and its newly generated ID will be returned. I have two possible solutions/implementations of that.

The first solution is trivial:

1. We check if name is in the table.
2. If not we insert a row with the name.
3. We select the row with the name and read the needed ID from that row.

I do not like this solution because it can happen that the first process checks if the name in the table, it sees that the name is not there, meanwhile another process adds the name to the table and then the first process tries to add the same name.

The second solution seems to be better:

1. For any name we use `insert if not exist`.
2. We select from the table the row containing the name and get its ID.

Is the second solution optimal or there are better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to avoid duplicate entries in a table is to create an unique constraint. The database will then check for you if the record is already there and fail if so. That should be the best in terms of reliability and performance.

Next, the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) suggests to use the function [last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) to fetch the ID instead of running a second query. This is actually the first question of the FAQ at all ;)

Comment: "unique constrain" and "last_insert_rowid" do not resolve the problem. For example the first process checks if a name is already in the table and sees that it is not. Then another process adds the name. The first process tries to add the same name. Because of "unique constrain" this operation fails. As a consequence  the first process cannot get the ID of the name with the "last_insert_rowid" because no insert by this process was done.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode, the first solution looks like this:

```py
cursor = db.execute("SELECT id FROM name_to_id WHERE name = ?", name)
if cursor.has_some_row:
    id = cursor["id"]
else:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO name_to_id(name) VALUES(?)", name)
    id = db.last_insert_rowid
```

and the second like this:

```py
db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO name_to_id(name) VALUES(?)", name)
cursor = db.execute("SELECT id FROM name_to_id WHERE name = ?", name)
id = cursor["id"]
```

The first solution requires a transaction around both commands, but this would be a good idea for the second solution, too, to avoid the overhead of multiple implicit transactions.

The second solution requires a unique constaint on `name`, but this would be a good idea for the first solution, too, for correctness and to speed up the `name` lookups.

Both solution use two SQL statements, and have similar speed.
(The second searches the row two times, but that data is cached.)
So there isn't anything obvious that makes one better that the other.