# Concurrent insertion using the last rowid in the same statement

Tags: sqlite, subquery

Given the following minimal database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "sites" (
    "host"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "info"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("host")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "ping" (
    "host"  INTEGER,
    "stamp" INT NOT NULL,
    "ping"  INT NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Insert a new row in to the *sites* table if it does not exist.
2. Get the ROWID of the new entry if created. Otherwise, get the ROWID of a row where *host* matches an existing row (using the same *host* as the previous step).
3. Insert a new row in to the *ping* table using the ROWID from the previous step.

Is it possible to achieve all three steps within a **single SQlite statement**? Due to age and limitations of the target system, this would ideally work on SQLite 3.3.6 (that's 3.3.6, *not* 3.36).

A psuedo-example is below:

```
WITH newid AS (SELECT ROWID FROM (INSERT OR REPLACE INTO hosts (host) VALUES ('192.168.0.1'))) INSERT INTO ping (host, stamp, ping) VALUES (newid, 1701294795, 20)
```

The following questions seem similar, but aren't quite what I am going for:

- [Non-nested example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python)
- [Two statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074903/how-to-construct-an-sqlite-table-that-assign-and-returns-ids-to-any-name)

To clarify, I am aware of how to achieve this using multiple statements, but I am curious to see if it can be done in a single statement. The old SQLite version precludes the use of the [RETURNING](https://www3.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) operator in the INSERT statement.